# Matrix assignment in place?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, variable-assignment

Suppose I initialize a matrix as follows:

```
import scipy
m = scipy.zeros((10, 10))
```

Now I do some calculations, and I want to assign the results into `m`. In the assignment, the size of `m` doesn't change, so I think it will be faster if the assignment is done in place.

```
m = scipy.array([[i * j for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)])
```

I am worried that in the above code, a temporary matrix is created holding the results, and then `m` is assigned to this value. This is inefficient because it involves allocating a new matrix. A more efficient solution is to store the values directly in `m`, which could be expressed like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        m[i,j] = i * j
```

But suppose that a generator expression is much more convenient for me, in the way that I've arranged my code.

What I want to know is this: In the generator expression above, am I doing an extra matrix allocation?

Comment: Array allocation might seem expensive if you're used to languages like C, but it's **dirt cheap** compared to the intrinsic overhead of CPython's no-JIT bytecode interpretation and dynamic everything. If you want NumPy/SciPy code to be efficient, the most crucial thing is to use NumPy vectorized operations to push the work into C-level loops that avoid all that overhead. Trying to minimize allocations first won't help much, and might even make your code slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do some actual time tests:

```
In [793]: timeit m=np.array([[i*j for j in range(N)] for i in range(M)])
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.8 µs per loop
In [794]: %%timeit
   .....: m=np.zeros((N,M),int)
   .....: for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        m[i,j] = i*j
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.2 µs per loop
```

So preallocation and assignment is slightly faster - but not drastically so.

Contrast that with a vector multiplication:

```
In [796]: timeit np.arange(M)[:,None]*np.arange(N)[None,:]
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.1 µs per loop
```

Do the same for larger array:

```
In [797]: N,M=1000,1000
In [798]: timeit m=np.array([[i*j for j in range(N)] for i in range(M)])
1 loops, best of 3: 325 ms per loop
In [799]: %%timeit
m=np.zeros((N,M),int)
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        m[i,j] = i*j
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 338 ms per loop
In [800]: timeit np.arange(M)[:,None]*np.arange(N)[None,:]
100 loops, best of 3: 12.5 ms per loop
```

The 2 iterations remain neck-to-neck; the vectorized is much better.

I can shave a bit of time of the iterations with `fromiter`, but nothing like the vectorized.

```
In [805]: timeit np.fromiter([i*j for j in range(N) for i in range(M)],int).reshape(N,M)
1 loops, best of 3: 235 ms per loop
```

This is a frequent question, and I am just too lazy to search for the best duplicate. :)  Usually people claim their calculation is some complex blackbox that only takes scalars, so there's no way to vectorize it.

There is a `np.vectorize` function that wraps your calculation, but it is intended to streamline things like broadcasting, and makes no claim about speeding up the code.  It still has to iterate.

If the calculation is small and fast it is worth while paying attention to the iteration method, but if it is complex, the proportion of time spent on the iteration mechanics is small, and you should focus on the speed of the blackbox.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first solution, the list comprehension, is that it produces a list of lists and assigns that to `m`. However, from your very first statement, you seem to want `m` to be a numpy array (which is what is created behind the scenes when executing `scipy.zeros()`). So, you've essentially created an array, then overwritten it with a list. If you want to keep the data structure as a `np.array`, your nested `for` loops are the best way to go.

Also, you said "*matrix*", but created an array. If you want an actual matrix (for example, to do matrix math), pass your nested list comprehension to `np.matrix()`:

```
# assuming you've already run `import numpy as np`
In [5]: m = np.matrix([[i * j for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)])

In [6]: m
Out[6]: 
matrix([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
        [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
        [ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36],
        [ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
        [ 0,  6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54],
        [ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63],
        [ 0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72],
        [ 0,  9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]])
```

Heck, even if you wanted an array after all, pass the nested listcomp to the array constructor like above, and you're all set.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `scipy.array(...)` in the assignment. Edited the question. So you're saying the assignment is better than the for loop? Which is faster?

Comment: I would discourage use of `np.matrix` - unless the OP is wedded to old MATLAB operations.

Comment: @hpaulj why is that?

Comment: A `np.matrix` is a subclass of `np.ndarray`, that among other things will always be 2d.  That makes somethings simpler, but otherwise is restrictive.  It's matrix multiplication expression is simpler, but element by element multiplication more complicated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117660/numpy-ndarray-multiplication-switching-to-matrix-multiplication is a recent example where an inadvertent switch to `matrix` causes problems.

Comment: @hpaulj interesting, thanks for the explanation. So basically the take-home is don't use `np.matrix` if at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

The second assignment (generator) does create a new matrix.
If you use python's [id() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), you can see that m points to a different location after that assignment.

For example:

```
>> import scipy
>> m = scipy.zeros((10, 10))
>> id(m)
4455211696
>> m = scipy.array([[i * j for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)])
>> id(m)
4478936688
```