# Numpy ndarray multiplication switching to matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

This is the error I am getting:

```
File "/data/eduardoj/linear.py", line 305, in _fit_model
        de_dl = (dl_dt + de_dt) * dt_dl
      File "/data/eduardoj/MSc-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 343, in __mul__
        return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    ValueError: shapes (1,53097) and (1,53097) not aligned: 53097 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

And this is the piece of code of numpy where it is crashing:

```
   340     def __mul__(self, other):                                           
>* 341         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :                
   342             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors                  
   343             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))                         
   344         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :          
   345             return N.dot(self, other)                                   
   346         return NotImplemented
```

(There is a break point there `>*` )

In my script I have a loop containing the following line:

```
de_dl = (dloss_dt + dr_dt) * dt_dl
```

The expected types and shapes for `de_dl`, `dloss_dt`, `dr_dt` and `dt_dl` are:

```
ndarray float32 (1, 53097)
```

So, I just want to compute the element-wise multiplication. I am using pudb3 for debugging my script. I checked that in the first iteration (`i == 0`) it works great (initially producing zeros). I notice that for this first iteration the thread did **NOT** reach the break-point I set. In the next iteration (`i==1`), I decided to stopped right before to calling the multiplication just to make sure the type and shape of `dloss_dt`, `dr_dt` and `dt_dl` were the still the same. They were.

Though they were the same, it seems that the program went through a different set of steps and some how ended in this `N.dot` multiplication.

So, I am asking for any clue of what might be keeping me from operating just a simple element-wise multiplication.

Comment: It looks as though `dl_dt` and/or `de_dt` is being cast to an `np.matrix` rather than an `np.ndarray` (`*` does matrix multiplication rather than elementwise multiplication for `np.matrix`). Since the first iteration works OK, this must be happening somewhere after that line in your code.

Comment: I put a break point to check its type right before executing this line. In the next iteration It was still an np.ndarray

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only way you could *possibly* see that error is if `(dl_dt + de_dt)` is an `np.matrix` (or some other derived class). Before the line `de_dl = (dl_dt + de_dt) * dt_dl`, insert a `print` statement: `print(type(dl_dt), type(de_dt))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought I checked the type of `(dl_dt + de_dt)`, but actually I had checked only its shape. You are completely right. `>>> type((d_loss_dt + d_regularization_dt))  
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>   
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet of numpy source code you showed in your question corresponds to the [`__mul__` method of `np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L340-L346).

This method gets called when you right-multiply a matrix object with another matrix or array, i.e. `A * B` is equivalent to `A.__mul__(B)` if `A` is a matrix (it doesn't matter whether `B` is an ndarray or matrix).

The only way that method could *possibly* be called is if `(dl_dt + de_dt)` is a matrix (or some other derived matrix class) rather than an ndarray. Therefore, either `dl_dt` or `de_dt` is being cast to a matrix somewhere in your code.

Since `__mul__` is not called on the first iteration, this must occur somewhere after line 305 in your code (`de_dl = (dl_dt + de_dt) * dt_dl`).